# Rails 6 Active Storage: Could not find or build blob: expected attachable... (issue when (re)setting attachment)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, attachment, rails-activestorage

In my application it is possible for an admin user to **suggest** and edit to another user's profile. I would like for the admin user to be able to suggest a (new) avatar for the non-admin user. Currently my user (user = `spkr` in my application) model has:

```
has_one_attached :image
has_one_attached :edited_image
```

Where `image` is the avatar image chosen by the user, and `edited_image` is the the avatar image suggested by the admin user.

When using the admin 'update' form, the `edited_image` is set

```
if spkr_params[:edited_image].present?
  @spkr.edited_image = spkr_params[:edited_image]
end
```

This successfully sets an attachment as `edited_image`.

When an admin user submits an edit non-admin user receives a confirmation email. When clicked I would like the `image` of the non-admin user to update.

```
...
if @spkr.edited_image.present?
   @spkr.image.purge
   @spkr.image = @spkr.edited_image
end
@spkr.save!
```

However I get the following error which raises on `@spkr.save!`:

```
Could not find or build blob: expected attachable, got #<ActiveStorage::Attached::One:0x00007fdcc44fa440 @name="edited_image", @record=#<Spkr id: 154... >>
```

Which is the `edited_image` from the `@spkr`:

```
@spkr.edited_image
=> #<ActiveStorage::Attached::One:0x00007fdcc44fa440 @name="edited_image", @record=#<Spkr id: 154...>>
```

My feeling is that @spkr.edited_image is not the 'attachable part' of @spkr.edited_image, but I am unsure how to resolve this.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved this by replacing the line

```
@spkr.image = @spkr.edited_image
```

with

```
@spkr.image = @spkr.edited_image.blob
```

This also worked:

```
@spkr.image.attach(@spkr.edited_image.blob)
```